# How to convert a Windows native virtual key code to Qt::Key?

Tags: qt, keycode, qkeyevent

I am working on a program which communicates with a windows native program, so it needs the actucal native virtual key code. How to convert from a Windows native virtual key code to Qt::Key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to a `QKeyEvent`, `key()` and `nativeVirtualKey` may help.

From Assistant, qthelp://com.trolltech.qt.472/qdoc/qkeyevent.html#details

Answer (score 6):

Look in the file `qt\src\gui\kernel\qkeymapper_win.cpp`