# From Qt::Key to native keyboard code

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to convert back from `Qt::Key` to the native keyboard code (either scan code or virtual key code)?

`QKeyEvent` has two methods:

```
nativeScanCode () const
quint32 nativeVirtualKey () const
```

So somewhere there needs to be a mapping between the native code and the `Qt:Key` . I am looking for the inverse function `Qt:Key` -> native code

According to " [How to convert a Windows native virtual key code to Qt::Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482213/how-to-convert-a-windows-native-virtual-key-code-to-qtkey) " I would expect the mapping in `qt\src\gui\kernel\qkeymapper_win.cpp` but this file does not exist in my src path **(Qt 5.2)**.

-- Edit (Samoth's answer) --

I am able to locate the files now, silly mistake on my side. What I am really looking for is a way to

1. either convert `Qt:Key` to native / virtual code
2. or vice versa

Unfortunately I did not find this method so far.